# Gem install error string contains null byte ERROR

Tags: ruby

I recently tried to install a gem and ..

```
C:\Users\HP>gem install watir
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        string contains null byte
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: How have you installed ruby?

Comment: @lacostenycoder using rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: try using rvm it will likely solve a lot of problems.  https://rvm.io/rvm/install